# VBA Excel: Userform to populate spreadsheet only updates the same row

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel 2013, I'm creating a user form to populate a spreadsheet.

The code is updating only the 2nd row of the spreadsheet, instead of jumping to the next line when clicking "OK", it keeps updating the same row.

I need it to update the 1st row (A6) and go on to the next blank one.

Current Code for the "OK" Button:

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()

    Dim RowCount As Long
    Dim ctl As Control

    RowCount = Worksheets("Serviços-Componentes").Range("A4").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    With Worksheets("Serviços-Componentes").Range("A4")

        .Offset(RowCount, 0).value = Me.txtServ.value
        .Offset(RowCount, 1).value = Me.cmbFluxos.value & "." & Me.cmbSubFluxos

        If Me.checkMQ.value = True Then
            .Offset(RowCount, 2).value = "X"
        Else
            .Offset(RowCount, 2).value = ""
        End If

        If Me.checkHTTP.value = True Then
            .Offset(RowCount, 3).value = "X"
        Else
            .Offset(RowCount, 3).value = ""
        End If

        If Me.checkLU62.value = True Then
            .Offset(RowCount, 4).value = "X"
        Else
            .Offset(RowCount, 4).value = ""
        End If

        If Me.checkDpower.value = True Then
            .Offset(RowCount, 5).value = "X"
        Else
            .Offset(RowCount, 5).value = ""
        End If

        If Me.checkIIB.value = True Then
            .Offset(RowCount, 6).value = "X"
        Else
            .Offset(RowCount, 6).value = ""
        End If

        If Me.checkWAS.value = True Then
            .Offset(RowCount, 7).value = "X"
        Else
            .Offset(RowCount, 7).value = ""
        End If

        If Me.checkMFM.value = True Then
            .Offset(RowCount, 8).value = "X"
        Else
            .Offset(RowCount, 8).value = ""
        End If

        .Offset(RowCount, 9).value = Me.txtReq.value
        .Offset(RowCount, 10).value = Me.txtResp.value
    End With

    ' Clear the form
     For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(ctl) = "ComboBox" Then
            ctl.value = ""
        ElseIf TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
            ctl.value = False
        End If
     Next ctl
End Sub
```

Comment: What line does it mess up on when you step through the code with the debugger?

Comment: No errors whatsoever. The code is "working". But it only writes data to row 7. I need it to write to 6 and then the next blank below.

Comment: So, when you step through the code in the debugger it executes each line correctly and when you expect it to?

Comment: Yes, the code runs fine to populate the correct data to the spreadsheet. But keeps writing only to the same row, overwriting anything already there.

Comment: I've managed to fix it. Seems that rowcount was not working, so I changed the variable declaration to Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).row